# In React.js, how can you check if prop exists before mapping it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an app getting data from a websocket connection that is really fast and is causing errors with the data in state. I'm. passing an array of just 15 items into a child component, however it is an array of tuples. When I map it, I need to deconstruct each tuple to render each item. However, every 30 seconds or so the component is receiving data that is corrupted and causing the erorr:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

At the line item[0] because item is undefined. I have tried several types of logic to make this mapping conditional based on the contents of the property. Below is Array.isArray(topAsks[0]), i have also tried topAsks.length > 2. However it is still going past and trying to map the undefined array.

Is there a better way to do this? That is being able to check that it is not undefined before mapping?

Also above commented out I was thinking of doing this with a for loop and then mapping each single array (bypassing the need to access an inner array), seems weird, but perhaps that is an effective way of doing this?

```
import React from 'react';


function Orderbook({topAsks, topBids}) {
  // let askQuant = [];
  // let askPrice = [];
  // let rBids = [];
  // for(let i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
  //   for(let j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
  //     rAsks.push(topAsks[i][j])
  //   }
  // }
  // console.log(topAsks)
  return (
    <div className="ob-cont">
      <div className="ob-title-cont">
        <div className="ob-title-marketsize"></div>
        <div className="ob-title-price"></div>
      </div>
       <div className="ob-sell-cont">
       {Array.isArray(topAsks[0]) 
       ?
         topAsks.map((item, index) => (
           <div key={index} className="ob-sell-tile"> 
            <div className="ob-sell-tile">{item[0]} </div>
            <div className="ob-sell-tile">{item[1]} </div>
           </div>
          ))
          : <div className="ob-sell-tile"> </div> }
       </div>

    </div>
  );
}

export default Orderbook;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're facing is about reading `item[0]` when item is undefined.

A simple solution could be filter the truthy values inside `topAsks`

For instance do something like:

```
topAsks.filter(Boolean).map((item, index) => (
           <div key={index} className="ob-sell-tile"> 
            <div className="ob-sell-tile">{item[0]} </div>
            <div className="ob-sell-tile">{item[1]} </div>
           </div>
          ))
```

Otherwise you could filter the elements which are array with at least 2 elements:

```
topAsks.filter(a => Array.isArray(a) && a.length >= 2)
```

Once again you could check with the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) when `item[0]` or `item[1]` exists, if they don't you could provide a default fallback case with the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) :

```
 topAsks.map((item, index) => (
           <div key={index} className="ob-sell-tile"> 
            <div className="ob-sell-tile">{item?.[0] ?? 'default item[0]'} </div>
            <div className="ob-sell-tile">{item?.[1] ?? 'default item[1]'} </div>
           </div>
          ))
```

Comment: Perfect, absolutely outstanding! It looks like the first two work, but I can't seem to get the nullish coalescing operator working. I'll be saving these for sure. Thanks.